# String formatting doesn't appear properly in a ListView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, format

My goal is to create a ListView that contains a word followed by some number. Now, for this list the length of the word varies from entry to entry but every number should be at exactly the same width.

Here's an example of the desired output(in command line):

[image]

Naturally, for this problem the first thing that comes to mind is simply using String.format to right pad the appropriate amount of spaces in each word but doing that doesn't quite give me the right output.

Like so:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

arr.add(String.format("%-10s", "aaaaaa") + "10");
arr.add(String.format("%-10s", "aa") + "10");
arr.add(String.format("%-10s", "asdkaosds") + "10");
arr.add(String.format("%-10s", "aaaaaaaaaa") + "10");

ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);

ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.answers);

listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Output:

[image]

Simply replacing spaces with asterisks shows me that the appropriate amount of spaces has been padded

```
arr.add(String.format("%-10s", "aaaaaa").replace(' ','*') + "10");
arr.add(String.format("%-10s", "aa").replace(' ','*') + "10");
arr.add(String.format("%-10s", "asdkaosds").replace(' ','*') + "10");
arr.add(String.format("%-10s", "aaaaaaaaaa").replace(' ','*') + "10");
```

Output:

[image]

The only other logical explanation is that the length of each character varies.

So my question is:

**How do i solve this problem?**

Comment: Take two textviews. One aligned to left and another to right which will show numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right that "the length of each character varies".

Either you have to take 2 textview side by side as mentioned by @Pankaj Kumar.

But if you don't want to do that, you can use any monospaced font.

Example

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

    arr.add(String.format("%-10s", "aaaaaa") + "10");
    arr.add(String.format("%-10s", "aa") + "10");
    arr.add(String.format("%-10s", "asdkaosds") + "10");
    arr.add(String.format("%-10s", "aaaaaaaaaa") + "10");
    final Typeface mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSansMono.ttf");

    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr){
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            TextView item = (TextView) super.getView(position,convertView,parent);

            item.setTypeface(mTypeface);

            return item;
        }
    };
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.answers);

    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Here is the [link](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/classification/monospaced) of some monospaced fonts